# Counting records given criterias

Tags: sql, sas

I give up! I've been trying to make this work for some time now but I can't get the logic/and or code right.

What I'm trying to do is to count ongoing cases for every date in a defined period. I have a table looking basically like this:

```
CaseId   OpenDate   CloseDate
1        01JAN2014  05JAN2014
2        02JAN2014  04JAN2014
3        02JAN2014  .
4        03JAN2014  04JAN2014
5        06JAN2014  08JAN2014
6        07JAN2014  .
```

I created a data set iterating dates from today-30 to today as comparative dates (CompDate).

Definition of ongoing case is (CompDate <= OpenDate and CompDate < CloseDate) or CloseDate = .

My plan was to join the dates with the table and get something like this

```
CompDate   OngoingCases
01JAN2014  1
02JAN2014  3
03JAN2014  4
04JAN2014  2
05JAN2014  1
06JAN2014  2
07JAN2014  3
```

So far I've came up with this code which gives me something else..

```
proc sql;
create table Ongoing as
select distinct
a.CompDate,
count(distinct case when (a.CompDate <= datepart(b.caseopendate) and (a.CompDate < datepart(b.caseclosedate) or b.caseclosedate = . )) then b.caseid end) as Cases
from List_of_dates as a
left outer join dcms_cases as b
on a.Date
where
. 
.
group by a.Date
;
quit;
```

Comment: Johan, Could you describe in words what an ongoing case is... I dont think I understand what the formula means...  (CompDate <= OpenDate and CompDate < CloseDate) or CloseDate = .

Comment: @Johan Did you mean "CompDate >= OpenDate and CompDate < CloseDate"?

Comment: Johan, how do you not have a static compDate in your result set if it is created by subtracting 30 from today?

Answer (score 1):

I made a few assumptions:

1) You meant to say the comp was greater than open date but less than close date or closed date is missing

2) You want the final result set to show how many ongoing cases were there based off the open date rather than the comp date since the comp date would be one static value... based on your description.

I have code below that used your sample and named it 'AA1'. It will give you the result set below.

```
Data AA1;
  set AA1;
  Format CompDate date9. Ongoing $3.;
  CompDate = today() - 100;  /*Change this to whatever your criteria is for the comparison*/
  If ((CompDate >= opendate) and  (CompDate < closedate)) or (closedate = .) then Ongoing = 'Y'; else Ongoing = 'N';
run;

/*Sort table in order to do a count of the ongoing cases*/

proc sort data = AA1;
  by caseID CompDate Ongoing;
run;

/*Count how many ongoing cases exist based on the Open date values */

data AA1(rename= (count=OngoingCases));
  set AA1;
  count + 1;
  by opendate;
  if first.opendate then count = 1;
run;

/*Clean up to keep the variables you want in your result set */

data final;
  set new(keep=opendate ongoingCases);
run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need is to join two tables applying your condition with dates in `ON`-statement. The following SQL will do the trick:

```
proc sql;
  create table Ongoing as
  select a.CompDate, count(b.CaseId) as OngoingCases
  from List_of_dates a
  left join dcms_cases b
  on b.OpenDate<=a.CompDate and (b.CloseDate>a.CompDate or b.CloseDate=.)
  group by a.CompDate
  ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to iterate over your date range for every record in your dataset, and output records which satisfy your criteria...

```
%LET START = today()-30 ;
%LET END   = today() ;

data want ;
  set have ;
  do CompDate = &START to &END ;
    OngoingCase = (OpenDate <= CompDate < CloseDate) 
               or (OpenDate <= CompDate and missing(CloseDate)) ;
    if OngoingCase then output ;
  end ;
  format CompDate date9. ;
run ;

proc summary data=want nway ;
  class CompDate ;
  var OngoingCase ;
  output out=case_sum (drop=_:) sum= ;
run ;
```

Comment: Chris, tried your solution but ends up with an empty table. Ran the data part alone but with the same outcome.

Comment: I think it's because you're mixing dates and datetimes... I'm assuming OpenDate and CloseDate are dates - you may have them stored as SAS datetime values with a format of `dtdate9.` applied. Wrap `OpenDate` and `CloseDate` references in `datetime(...)` if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the current query slightly and moved the CASE condition to the WHERE clause.

```
proc sql;
create table Ongoing as
select distinct
a.CompDate,
count(distinct b.caseid ) as Cases
from List_of_dates as a
left outer join dcms_cases as b
on a.Date
where (a.CompDate <= datepart(b.caseopendate) and a.CompDate < datepart(b.caseclosedate)) 
or b.caseclosedate = . 
group by a.Date
;
quit;
```